# How does Autofac associate automatically resolved services to lifetimes

Tags: c#, autofac, idisposable

Hi I'm quite new to Autofac so maybe my understanding of lifetime-scopes is completely wrong, but I ran into the following issue when disposing automatically resolved services by disposing the lifetime.
My App.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule<MainModule>();
    var container = builder.Build();

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var mainWindow = scope.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

So I thought all the services (registered as instance per lifetime) that will be resolved while resolving my MainWindow will be associated to the scope. This would mean that all Services that implement IDisposable will be disposed when the lifetime-scope ends. But they are not.

I found out while trying this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule<MainModule>();
    var container = builder.Build();

    var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    container.Dispose();
}
```

that Autofac associates the automatically resolved services with the root-container not the scope when it resolves them automatically, because in this case the "Dispose" methods were called as intended.

Can someone explain me why this happens and what would be the best approach to handle the Disposal of these automatically resolved services?

By the way, by saying "automatically resolved" I want to indicate that it's not me who resolves the service manually, as in the case of my MainWindow where the Disposal works just fine with the lifetime scope.

Answer (score 1):

> This would mean that all Services that implement IDisposable will be
> disposed when the lifetime-scope ends.

Autofac does not dispose services that are registered as instances! why? because in case the resolved instances will be needed again to another different scope.

---

Let see an example, assume we have a class of `Foo`:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Guid _id;
    public ConsoleLog()
    {
        this_id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo has been disposed.");
    }

    public void GetId()
    {
        return this_id;
    }
}
```

And we are registering a `new Foo()` instance with `RegisterInstance`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Dispose1Test()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterInstance(new Foo());
    var container = builder.Build();
```

If you will want to handle two different scopes, autofac will save the instance of that `Foo` inside the builder:

```
    Guid guid1;
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        id1 = scope.Resolve<Foo>().GetId();
    }
        
    Guid guid2;
    using (var scope2 = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        id2 = scope.Resolve<Foo>().GetId(); //--> this will resolve the exact same instance!
    }

    //It **does not** print: "Foo has been disposed."
    Assert.AreEqual(guid1, guid2);
}
```

> what would be the best approach to handle the Disposal of these
> automatically resolved services

You can use the using statement to apply a dispose for all the container:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Dispose2Test()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();            
    builder.RegisterInstance(new Foo());
    using (var container = builder.Build())
    {
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            scope.Resolve<Foo>();
        }
    }
    //Should output "Foo has been disposed."
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for your answer. But does that mean even Instances that are registered as InstancePerLifetime are not disposed when the lifetime ends if they are not manually resolved from the scope? I see why it doesnt work with Registering as Instance, but why do we have InstancePerLifetime if the Instance is not disposed when the lifetime ends?

Comment: `Instances that are registered as InstancePerLifetime` What do you mean by that? Instances are registered to the DI. and then it can begin a scope of lifetime. I'm not familiar with the term `InstancePerLifetime`.

Comment: You can do the registration like: builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().InstancePerLifetimeScope(); And my question essentially is about what this "Method" is for if doesnt dispose Components when the lifetime where they are resolved ends

Comment: If you will add the `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`, tihs `Assert.AreEqual(guid1, guid2);` will return false, or in other words it will instantiate two different objects.

Comment: Here I have a git with some examples in autofac, you might find it useful: https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/DependencyInjectionAutofac